# How to display post names by News category

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want to display post names by News category. I am using following code but not working

```
<?php
    query_posts(array('&category_name=News&showposts=5'));
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Try `posts_per_page` instead of `showposts`

Comment: Not working it showing all the posts not taking category

Comment: In the administration, the name of your category (the name, not the label) is probably not `News`, and probably be `news`.

Comment: In administration its News. Need to change to news??

Comment: If the ID is `News` so no shouldn't change anything. I just noticed something, it's that you send an array to `query_posts`. `query_posts` expect a parameter string as parameter. The valid code should be : `query_posts('category_name=News&showposts=5')`

Comment: To be exact you can use an array, but parameters need to be separate inside it - you can't use a mix of those two methods.

Comment: We should just stop using `query_posts` altogether

Comment: First can you plz check Function Reference/query posts. check below link.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
  <?php

       $args = array('cat' => 5);  //pass news category Id.

        // The Query
        query_posts( $args );

        // The Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;

        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Where I will get news category id . I am unable to find on dashboard.

Comment: please read this [link]https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID

Comment: Its working now but check you passed args instead of arg. Thank You

Comment: yes, thank's @tushar For notify.